Shuffle a tf.data.Dataset before split only once
I'm using a tf.data.Dataset to feed the model.fit() method of my model.
The whole dataset can't fit into my RAM so I need to load it per batch so I thought about using the Dataset generator (tf.data.Dataset) to load it during the training and prefetch the batches.
The function I use to get the train, val and test dataset looks like this :
def get_all_datasets(batch_size=64):
    path = 'a/path'
    img_folder = 'src'
    mask_folder = 'masks'
    im_path = os.path.join(path, img_folder)
    mk_path = os.path.join(path, mask_folder)

    path = 'another/path/'
    img_folder = 'src'
    mask_folder = 'masks'
    im_path2 = os.path.join(path, img_folder)
    mk_path2 = os.path.join(path, mask_folder)

    # Create datasets
    ds1 = create_dataset(im_path, mk_path, 256, 256)
    ds2 = create_dataset(im_path2, mk_path2, 256, 256)
    ds = ds1.concatenate(ds2)

    # Shuffle the entire dataset once before splitting
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds).numpy(),
            reshuffle_each_iteration=True)

    # Split into training, validation, and test sets
    total_size = tf.data.experimental.cardinality(ds).numpy()
    train_size = int(total_size * 0.7)
    val_size = int(total_size * 0.15)
    test_size = total_size - train_size - val_size

    # Create separate datasets
    train_dataset = ds.take(train_size)
    remaining = ds.skip(train_size)
    val_dataset = remaining.take(val_size)
    test_dataset = remaining.skip(val_size)

    # Cache the datasets to prevent re-shuffling/re-loading
    train_dataset = train_dataset.cache().shuffle(batch_size).batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    val_dataset = val_dataset.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)
    test_dataset = test_dataset.cache().batch(batch_size).prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.AUTOTUNE)

    return train_dataset, val_dataset, test_dataset

The first shuffle is done to have an equivalent proportion of "scenarios" in the train, val and test. This shuffle must be done only once, to avoid polluting the train, val and test sets.
I don't know how I should avoid the reshuffling the whole set each time. Maybe this dataset method isn't the appropriated one too.

During the training, the whole dataset is shuffled twice, once for the train and another time for the validation. I see the shuffling buffer filling with the whole dataset cardinality.
I also thought about creating three folders (train, val and test) after shuffling once to get my split and then only shuffle the train data with the shuffle method, but I would be surprised if it's the easiest way to fix the problem ...
I tried setting an if statement before the shuffle to check if the shuffling has already be done but the shuffling still occurs. My thought are that the execution graph is already "scheduled" and the global variable was set to False during the lazy interpretation.
